# Mainthread ends before CompletabeObserver gets called

Tags: android, java-8, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

In the below code, I created an example to learn functional programming using Rx. I am trying to handle a HandlerThread as observable. In onResume(), I subscribe for Single.just observable to start the
HandlerThread.

The SingleObserver callbacks are called correctly. But, for the CompletableObserver in onLooperPrepared() it is never called, despite, Completable.complete() was called.

I posted also the logcat. Please have a look at it, and please let me know how why i do not receive any logs from CompletableObserver.

**code**:

```
onResume() {
    this.mMyHandlerThreadInitSingleObs = Single.just(this.getInitializedHandlerThread())
            .map(myHandlerThread->{
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "BEFORE .start()");
                myHandlerThread.start();
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "AFTER .start()");

                return this.mMyHandlerThread;
            });
    this.mMyHandlerThreadInitSingleObs
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this.getSingleObserver());

}
private static class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
    private final static String TAG_LOG = ActMain.TAG_LOG + "." + MyHandlerThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private Handler mHandler = null;

    MyHandlerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        Log.v(MyHandlerThread.TAG_LOG, "constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        super.onLooperPrepared();
        String TAG_LOG = MyHandlerThread.TAG_LOG + "." + "onLooperPrepared";
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "this.getLooper(): " + this.getLooper());

        Completable.create(emitter -> {
            if (this.getLooper() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG_LOG+"."+"Completable.create", "this.getLooper() initialized: " + this.getLooper());
                Completable.complete();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG_LOG+"."+"Completable.create", "this.getLooper() is null: " + this.getLooper());
                Completable.error(new NullPointerException(THROW_NPE_ON_LOOPER_NULL));
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.i(TAG_LOG, "[onSubscribe]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.i(TAG_LOG, "[onComplete]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG_LOG, "[onError]: e.getMessage(): " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}

private SingleObserver<MyHandlerThread> getSingleObserver() {
    String TAG_LOG = ActMain.TAG_LOG + "." + "getSingleObserver()";
    return new SingleObserver<MyHandlerThread>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, "[onSubscribe]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MyHandlerThread myHandlerThread) {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, "[onSuccess]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, "[onError]");
        }
    };
}
```

**logcat**:

```
2018-12-22 12:40:12.118 V/ActMain: onStart
2018-12-22 12:40:12.120 V/ActMain.MyHandlerThread: constructor called
2018-12-22 12:40:12.125 V/ActMain.getSingleObserver(): [onSubscribe]
2018-12-22 12:40:12.129 D/ActMain.onResume(): BEFORE .start()
2018-12-22 12:40:12.129 D/ActMain.onResume(): AFTER .start()
2018-12-22 12:40:12.130 V/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: ..
2018-12-22 12:40:12.130 01 D/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: this.getLooper(): Looper (my HandlerThread, tid 352) {1353cc7}
2018-12-22 12:40:12.131 01 V/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared: [onSubscribe]
2018-12-22 12:40:12.132 D/ActMain.MyHandlerThread.onLooperPrepared.Completable.create: this.getLooper() initialized: Looper (my HandlerThread, tid 352) {1353cc7}
2018-12-22 12:40:12.139 V/ActMain.getSingleObserver(): [onSuccess]
2018-12-22 12:40:12.436 I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.amrbakri.rxhandlerthread_01/.ActMain: +552ms
```

Comment: as i see you have the log of create to Completable . what are you expecting for ??

Comment: @RicardKollcaku i expected to receive logs from the CompletableObservable!!

Comment: you are receiving logs from  Completable create and subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that  Completable.complete(); doesn't make sense because this is a static function that return a Completable if you are trying to send the stream to oncomplete you need to call onComplete() of emitter like this.

```
    Completable.create(emitter -> {
        emitter.onComplete();
        System.out.println("1");
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            System.out.println("2");

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("3");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("4");
        }
    });
}
```